# Changing Footer Styles - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

I seem to be having re-occurring issues with styling individual parts of a wordpress page, but in this case it is the footer HTML code.

In the Footer, I have the following code:

```
<div id="Footer Shopping Info">
  <div class="Box">
    <div class="Box-Info">
      <div class="Box-Heading">

         <ul class="Shopping-Info-List">
            <h2>Shopping Info</h2>
            <li><a href="http://cutepinkboutique.com/Returns/">Returns</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://cutepinkboutique.com/Returns/">Expected Delivery</a> </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to individually style and change 
H2 with the following code:

```
.box h2 {
  color: #ff63b1;
}
```

but the H2 line is not turning pink. Why is this?

I seemed to be having this alot lately, and I know that 
its pulling from a global element. How can I box off
code so that I can change things individually?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's a "simple typographical error". I'm marking it as duplicate as the other question has quite important remarks and documentation about the error. As in using white-spaces in an element ID.

Answer (score 1):

> Dear `.box` is not the same as `.Box` these are two different classes when using css it is always best practice to use small letters.

so just change `<div class="Box">` to `<div class="box">`

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I didn't know that caps were taken into account. I'm a wannabe web developer ;)

Comment: Glad that solve your issue, you are welcome :)